# Javascript Object property accessor string with array position square brackets

Tags: javascript

For Example I have this Object structure.

```js
let data = {
  id: 2, 
  content: [
    {foo: "bar1"},
    {foo: "bar2"},
  ]
};
```

And the only thing I know is this String:

`content[0].foo`

How can I access the property with this square brackets in the string?

I know that you can access objects like this:

```js
data['content'] // (2) [{…}, {…}]
data['content'][0] // {foo: 'bar1'}
```

I tried to use something like this `data['content[0]']` but this is undefined because here js tries to get the key that has square brackets in it.

I have more complex data structures like this in my project: `data.content[0].carousel.images[3].id`.

**What is the best possible way to access the property only knowing the string to the correct property containing square brackets for the array positions?**

Comment: Just a side note that `content[0].bar` will give you `undefined`. `content[0]` has no `bar` property in the example.

Comment: You could use [some library](https://github.com/mariocasciaro/object-path) to access nested props.

Comment: Oh yes you are right that was a mistake while writing the question, thanks ill edit it

Comment: "What is the best possible way to access the property only knowing the string to the correct property containing square brackets for the array positions?"

None. There isn't one!

Comment: I ended up using this: 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-resolve-path